# Execute click handlers in order, to render elements only after an action is performed

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm trying to have jQuery listen for clicks only at a specific time. However when I add event listeners, such as `$("#box").click(function(){`, they seem to be executing before the code above them runs.

I created a text example where I have 2 different boxes listening for clicks and I only want the second one to listen after the first one has been clicked. After that I want them to stop listening. So for example `box1` should be able to be changed to red first and then `box2`.

I've tried searching around for this but haven't been able to find any good answers. I also tried adding `if` statements, but then the second box never executes. Any help is greatly appreciated.

```js
pass = 0;

function change() {
  console.log("enter change");
  $("#box").click(function() {
    $(this).css("background-color", "red");
    pass = 1;
  })

  if (pass > 0) {
    $("#box2").click(function() {
      $(this).css("background-color", "red");
    })
  }
}
```

```css
div {
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  background-color: black;
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 10px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="box"></div>
<div id="box2"></div>
<button onclick="change()"> change</button>
```

Comment: I'd strongly suggest you update your version of jQuery. 1.4.2 is almost 9 years out of date.

Comment: "I only want the second one to listen after the first one has been clicked"...in that case, move the code which creates the second listener inside the the "click" event for the first one - that logic is simple enough: if you want some code to run when an event happens, then put that code inside the event handler. "After that I want them to stop listening"...for that you can use [.off()](http://api.jquery.com/off/) - you'll need at least v1.7 of jQuery. Again, put the .off() call inside the same item's "click" event - so once it's clicked, it stops listening for more clicks.

Comment: thank you I'll grab the new one next time

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To make this work I'd suggest using a different pattern. Having click handlers attached at dynamic times can get confusing and make the code more complex than it needs to be.

A simpler and more effective solution would be to bind all the event handlers when the page loads, and conditionally check within each if the page is in a state in which this event handler is allowed to execute its own logic.

In other words, you could add a class on click of `#box` and then only allow the class to be added on `#box2` once it has been applied to `#box`. Try this:

```js
$('#box').one('click', function() {
  $(this).addClass('foo');
});

$('#box2').click(function() {
  if ($('#box').hasClass('foo')) {
    $(this).addClass('foo').off('click');    
  }
});
```

```css
div {
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  background-color: black;
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 10px;
}
div.foo {
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="box"></div>
<div id="box2"></div>
```

There's a few things to note here. Firstly, jQuery 1.4.2 is very outdated; almost 9 years in fact. You need to updated it to at least 1.12.4 if you require legacy browser support, or the latest on the 3.x branch if not.

Secondly, don't use inline event handlers, such as `onclick`. Use unobtrusive event handlers. As you're already using jQuery it's easy to just use the `click()` method.

This also uses `one()`, to add an event handler which can only fire once, and `off()` to remove the click handler once it's been executed successfully for the first time.

It also uses `addClass()` over `css()`, as the latter requires you to put CSS logic within your JS, which should be avoided where at all possible.